# Please explain how apex controller works

Tags: apex, custom-controller

I don't understand why the following controller updates an account.

My thoughts that there should be `public void setAccount() {...}` method so changes in view will be available in controller.

Custom Controller:

```
public class MyController {

    private final Account account;

    public MyController() {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update account;
        return null;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Congratulations {!$User.FirstName}">
            You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controller had:

```
private String s;

public String getStringValue() {
    return s;
}
```

and your page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!stringValue}"/>
```

then I think you would get a compilation or runtime error.

But in your example the page is not trying to replace the `Account` object i.e. update the `account` field, but is in fact updating a child field of that object, the `account.name` field, and that can be done because the `Account` SObject has the necessary setter (and getter).

Your Visualforce is essentially doing:

```
controller.getAccount().setName(...)
```

i.e. it only needs an Apex getter for Account.

Comment: Yes, you right, if you have in VFP `<apex:inputText value="{! stringValue }"/>` you will get `Read only property 'MyController.stringValue'`. The same I expect from `account` member field, why I'm not getting the same error for `account`?

Comment: @Edelrabe Because you are not updating account, you are updating a field of the account and that field has a setter. I've added a it to the answer.

Comment: So you are saying that the _reference_ to `account` has no setter, but the Account SObject has setters for its fields. I think I got it. Thanks

Comment: @Edelrabe Yep, you `get` a reference to Account and then `set` a value on that reference.

Answer (score 1):

when user clicks the button, controller save() method executed. Inside there are DML operation which invoke update.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>

public PageReference save() {
    update account;
    return null;
}
```

> The button executes an action defined by a controller, and then either refreshes the current page, or navigates to a different page based on the PageReference variable that is returned by the action.

As this is a custom controller, you can name your method as you want,

for example:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveMyAccount}" value="save"/>
```

and in controller:

```
public PageReference saveMyAccount() {
    update account;
    return null;
}
```

BTW, apex supports Syntactic sugar for getters and setter.
[Defining Action Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_setter_methods.htm)

Comment: Hi Denis, I know about actions, but my question was how `account` variable knows about changes, if there is no setter for this variable. Thanks

Comment: SF implicitly creates setter for you. I prefer to use more obviously way: 

`public Account aAccount { get; set;}`

 and init this member variable in constructor or other methods. 

`this.aAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id =:someVar]`

Answer (score 0):

Apex controllers we have 3 types of methods other then constructor.
1 Getters (are used to get data from controllers to Visualforce)
2 Setters (to set data in controllers from vf pages)
3 action method (methods which return page reference)

In the above controller Save method is an action method which is implicitly updating the Account record by DML.

that's why your account records are getting updated.

To learn more about page lifecycle refer this link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm